# vbs passing parameters weird behavior

Tags: vbscript

i am creating a .vbs file that should open access, and inside access a form call "Issue Details", but passing a parameter, meaning that if i have 10 issues in my "Issues" table a vbs file is created for each one and when clicked should open the right record(would be one ID for each record in the table). It is so far opening access and it is opening the form(Issue Details) but it is blank. What am i missing? Help, getting crazy here ... Check code below. The weird thing here is that if i double click it again it will refresh and open the right record without opening anymore windows..
How can i fix that? I dont want to do it twice :)

```
Public Sub sendMRBmail(mrbid)
DoCmd.OpenForm "Issue Details", , , "[ID] = " & mrbid
End Sub

Private Sub Create_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command48_Click
Dim snid As Integer
snid = Me.ID
Dim filename As String
filename = "S:\Quality Control\vbs\QC" & snid & ".vbs" 
Dim proc As String
proc = Chr(34) & "sendMRBmail" & Chr(34)

Dim strList As String

strList = "On Error Resume Next" & vbNewLine
strList = strList & "dim accessApp" & vbNewLine
strList = strList & "set accessApp = createObject(" & Chr(34) & "Access.Application" & Chr  (34)")" & vbNewLine
strList = strList & "accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase(" & Chr(34) & "S:\Quality Control\Quality  DB\Quality Database.accdb" & Chr(34) & ")" & vbNewLine
strList = strList & "accessApp.Run " & proc & "," & Chr(34) & snid & Chr(34) & vbNewLine
strList = strList & "set accessApp = nothing" & vbNewLine
Open filename For Output As #1
Print #1, strList
Close #1

Err_Command48_Click:

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
 MsgBox "Email Error #: " & Err.Number & ", " & "Description: " & Err.Description
  Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: it could be possible its issuing the command before access is fully open.  Maybe put a pause in there to allow access to open fully.

Comment: Your code is obviously **not** VBScript. Is this question perhaps about Access VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Changed instruction below, adding acFormEdit to it and it worked:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Issue Details", , , "[ID] = " & mrbid, acFormEdit
```