# Access VBA passing parameters vbs file

Tags: ms-access, vba

i am creating a .vbs file that should open access, and inside access a form call "Issue Details", but passing a parameter, meaning that if i have 10 issues in my "Issues" table a vbs file is created for each one and when clicked should open the right record(would be one ID for each record in the table). It is so far opening access and it is opening the form(Issue Details) but it is blank. What am i missing? Help, getting crazy here ... Check code below. The weird thing here is that if i double click it again it will refresh and open the right record without opening anymore windows.. How can i fix that? I dont want to do it twice :)

```
Public Sub sendMRBmail(mrbid)
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Issue Details", , , "[ID] = " & mrbid
    End Sub

    Private Sub Create_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_Command48_Click
    Dim snid As Integer
    snid = Me.ID
    Dim filename As String
    filename = "S:\Quality Control\vbs\QC" & snid & ".vbs" 
    Dim proc As String
    proc = Chr(34) & "sendMRBmail" & Chr(34)

    Dim strList As String

    strList = "On Error Resume Next" & vbNewLine
    strList = strList & "dim accessApp" & vbNewLine
    strList = strList & "set accessApp = createObject(" & Chr(34) & "Access.Application" & Chr  (34)")" & vbNewLine
    strList = strList & "accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase(" & Chr(34) & "S:\Quality Control\Quality     DB\Quality Database.accdb" & Chr(34) & ")" & vbNewLine
    strList = strList & "accessApp.Run " & proc & "," & Chr(34) & snid & Chr(34) & vbNewLine
    strList = strList & "set accessApp = nothing" & vbNewLine
    Open filename For Output As #1
    Print #1, strList
   Close #1

   Err_Command48_Click:

   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Email Error #: " & Err.Number & ", " & "Description: " & Err.Description
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

This is what is inside a created vbs file

```
On Error Resume Next
dim accessApp
set accessApp = GetObject("S:\Quality Control\Quality    DB\Quality Database.accdb")
accessApp.Run"sendMRBmail","231"
set accessApp = nothing
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [vbs passing parameters weird behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646849/vbs-passing-parameters-weird-behavior)

Comment: it is a dup but I am assuming it was created to add the right tags.  The code above looks like it is creating the VBS file.  Post the contents of one of the VBS files for review.

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate, i moved it here to add the right tags but did not deleted from there.

Comment: See what is inside of a vbs file below                                                                 On Error Resume Next
   dim accessApp
   set accessApp = GetObject("S:\Quality Control\Carlos Quality    DB\Quality Database Playground.accdb")
   accessApp.Run"sendMRBmail","231"
   set accessApp = nothing

Comment: Thanks @Sorceri, See what is inside of a vbs file, timing did not work.                                                                  'On Error Resume Next
    dim accessApp
    set accessApp = GetObject("S:\Quality Control\Carlos Quality    DB\Quality Database Playground.accdb")
    accessApp.Run"sendMRBmail","231"
    set accessApp = nothing'

Comment: Why don't you do all the work from within VBA? Why are you creating a VBS file?

Comment: Because that vbs file is being sent inside an email as a link, so users just click the link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all that made inputs, i already found the answer. I added acFormEdit at the end of my DoCmd and it worked, check below:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Issue Details", , , "[ID] = " & mrbid, acFormEdit
```